# What can I do to reduce the interaction lag of a Windows 10 VM?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox, lag

I'm using a Windows 10 VM on my (Devuan Chimaera) GNU/Linux machine, to test-build some code of mine. I am not using that VM as a "regular  user", so I don't care about all sorts of eye candy, support for exotic hardware, services that I would expect on an actual desktop/laptop machine etc. I'm experiencing a lot of lag interacting with the Windows UI after boot - even though I haven't even started any apps:

- Keypresses sometime take seconds (if not worse) to have any effect.
- I can see icons being repainted.
- Windows/dialogs/menus are often opened blank, or with just a frame and I wait for them to be painted.

I'm using Oracle's VirtualBox VM framewor. I gave the VM 4 GB of memory and 1 full core.

What can I do, inside and outside the VM, to reduce this lag? I am willing to be rather flexible, e.g. boot in text mode and SSH into the machine; replace Oracle VirtualBox with something else (vmware, QEMU, whatever); burn some incense and pray real hard; etc.

Comment: My suggestions will be a bit hard to implement so just suggestions.  (A) try a different virtualizing app like VMware.  (B) high performing virtual machines usually need an SSD drive. I have VMware V16 on a Windows 10 Host (all different than you), fast SSD drive and 16 GB of memory. My virtual machines (Linux) run without and drag or lag.

Comment: Have you installed the VirtualBox "Guest Additions" for Windows? Without them, you'll be using the generic slow VESA graphics driver.

Comment: @user1686: I think I haven't. What are those, exactly? And - do I install them inside, or outside the VM?

Comment: More cores (all of them) and more RAM. When is the last time you used a PC with only one core?

Comment: @einpoklum: It's a set of drivers for the guest OS (inside the VM) which are meant to handle the custom devices that VirtualBox emulates. Click "Insert 'Guest Additions' ISO" in the VM's menu. (Note that in some Linux distributions, you _may_ need to download the actual ISO as a separate package outside of the VM before it becomes available in VirtualBox.) VMware, VirtualPC, Qemu have similar packages as well.

Comment: @DanielB: Windows 10 needs more than 4GB, or 2 cores, to have responsive UI? Surely you jest... not even Microsoft are that cretinous :-(

Comment: I'd say give it another core if you can. I've run 10 on some potato grade systems (even a c2d box with 1gb of ram and a cheap SSD upgrade) but never anything with less than 2 cores

Comment: @user1686: What is the vmware equivalent of the virtualbox "guest addition"?

Comment: @einpoklum: VMware calls it "[VMware Tools](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/340)". _(Incidentally, VirtualBox can now emulate the VMware 'VMSVGA' graphics adapter as well.)_

Comment: Windows 10 or 11 VM in either VirtualBox or VMware without Guest Additions or VMWare tool will run like a _stone dog_. I give 4 GB (out of 16 GB on the host) and they run just fine. Cores I set to 'automatic'. Also they are on an SSD

Answer (score 1):

Oracle VBOX is not the fastest virtual app today. Try VMware Workstation V16 as that is a very efficient virtual app. I use this.

Then for heavy duty virtual machines, consider a fast SSD drive.

Make sure the host machine has 16GB or more real memory.

Virtual Apps usually require Tools or Extensions to be installed to ensure proper mouse movement but normally do not affect performance lag. If you need help with guest extensions, follow this guide.

[Install Windows 10 guest extensions](https://pureinfotech.com/install-guest-additions-windows-10-virtualbox/)

> Open Virtual Box.
>
> Right-click the virtual machine, select the Start submenu and choose
> the Normal Start option.
>
> Sign in to your Windows 10 account.
>
> Click the Devices menu and select the Insert Guest Additions CD image
> option.
>
> Open File Explorer in the virtual machine (Windows key + E keyboard
> shortcut).
>
> Click on This PC from the left side.
>
> Under the “Devices and drives” section, double-click to open the
> VirtualBox Guest Additions disc.
>
> Double-click the VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe file to launch the
> installer.
>
> Click the Next button.
>
> Click the Next button again.
>
> Click the Install button.
>
> Select the Reboot now option.
>
> Click the Finish button.

Comment: What vmware variant should I download? They have [a zillion "products"](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/downloads/#all_products).

Comment: I use VMware Workstation V16 Pro under VMware.com desktop products. Yes they have lots of products and have been spun off from Dell recently.

Comment: I think VMWare Workstation Pro is not gratis. I don't suppose you're tried "player"?

Comment: I have and have used Player. It is OK for basic uses. Pro is not free but much more flexible and configurable.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I've done to improve responsivity:

1. Disable animations and similar eye-candy:

   In Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings (it's in there, you may need to scroll down to find it), in the Visual Effects tab, select Adjust for Performance. A simpler, less-animated theme will now be used.
2. Disable transparency:

   Apparently the combination of VirtualBox + Windows 10 transparency effects in window, dialog and menu backgrounds don't play nice together; thus, in fact, some of the paint delays I was experiencing weren't really delays, but failure to properly paint areas due to transparency effects. These can be disabled by entering the Settings   (a.k.a. sucky Control Panel spinoff) utility, and in Personalization > Colors , turning off  "Transparency effects". You'll get nice ugly flat backgrounds... which paint faster. See also [this description](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-10/how-to-disable-transparency-effects-in-windows-10-2/) of how to do it.